# Python isn't recognizing integers apart from 1

Tags: python

Python isn't recognizing any number apart from 1 as an integer.  When i enter a number to be multiplied the program will run the except ValueError even though i have entered an integer.  This is the code i have.

```
    Total = 0
    Tsl = 100
    receipt = open("Receipt.txt", "w")
    while True:
    try:
        Prod_Code = input("Enter a code or Done to get your final receipt: ")
        if len(Prod_Code) == 8:
            int(Prod_Code)
            with open("Data Base.txt", "r") as searchfile:
                for line in searchfile:
                    if Prod_Code in line:
                        print(line)
                        Quantity = input("What quantity of this product do you want? ")
                        Total += float(line.split(",")[2] * int(Quantity))
                        print(Quantity)
                        print(Total)
                        receipt.write(line)

        elif Prod_Code == "Done":
            print("Bye Bye")
            print(receipt)
            receipt.close

            exit()

        else:
            print("Incorrect length, try again")


    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer")
```

The error occurs when i enter any other number than 1 when i enter the quantity.  If anyone can see the problem any input will be appreciated

Comment: There are multiple problems here, the most severe I guess is `float(line.split(",")[2] * int(Quantity))` -> `float(line.split(",")[2]) * int(Quantity)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
Total += float(line.split(",")[2] * int(Quantity))
```

multiplies the *string* `line.split(",")[2]` by the `Quantity` converted to integer. And then attempts to convert the resulting string to a float.

Eg, if `line.split(",")[2]` is '1.2' and `Quantity` is '3' then

```
line.split(",")[2] * int(Quantity)
```

results in '1.21.21.2', which can't be converted to float. :)

Instead do

```
Total += float(line.split(",")[2]) * int(Quantity)
```

---

BTW, you aren't actually closing the `receipt` file. You're just emitting the method name and discarding it. So change

```
receipt.close
```

to

```
receipt.close()
```

Even better: use `with` blocks to open all your files so they get closed automatically.

---

I should also mention that the plain `exit()` function is primarily intended for use in the interactive interpreter, and it's not guaranteed to exist in all environments. To ensure portability use `sys.exit()` instead. OTOH, it's not really needed here, you can just `break` out of that `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be in inputing the Promo_Code , you are using input so if your promo code is abcdefgh then you must input it as 'abcdefgh' or "abcdefgh" because input in python 2 cannot take automatic decisions . For sake of simplicity always use raw_input() for inputting strings,
Also in your elif convert reciept.close to reciept.close().

Comment: I assume that joe is using Python 3, due to the fact that he's using the `print()` function, not the `print` statement. And of course in Python 3 `raw_input()` is now `input()`, and the old, dangerous `input()` no longer exists.

Comment: yeah ! I assume you are right except if Joe didn't do something like `from __future__ import print_function` (which he most probably won't do .) Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Well, if Joe _is_ using Python 2 and doing the `__future__` import he should include that in his code. :) FWIW, the current policy of the SO Python community is to assume that questions are Python 3 unless there's clear evidence that the OP is using Python 2. People shouldn't be using Python 2 for new code since it will reach its EOL (End Of Life) in 2020.